# 1. / this.norm(); Is `1.` just syntactic sugar?

Tags: java, double

I am new to Java and did not exactly know how to search for this. Because googling for `1. double java` does not give me any pleasing search results.

I came across this code:

```
public Vector normalize() {
    final double inorm = 1. / this.norm();
    return smult(inorm);
}
```

One might say this code is too explicit anyway, having a `final` local variable. I think due to `this.norm()` returns a `double` anyway, `1 / this.norm()` would have had the same effect.

Is `1.` just some syntactic sugar, and means the same as `1.0` does? Would something different (like euclidean division) happen if `this.norm()` returned an `int` and I wrote `1` instead of `1.`?

Comment: Yes, it's just syntactic sugar; it's exactly equivalent to `1 / this.norm()`.

Comment: Yes, `1.` is the same as `1.0` and if you didn't have the `.` and `norm()` returned an `int` then you would be doing integer division which truncates the value.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that isn't true if `norm()` returns an integral type.

Comment: @clcto: the OP stated explicitly that that wasn't the case.

Comment: Yes to pretty much everything you said. However, it's not really syntactic sugar. It's just causing the tokeniser to parse a floating point literal instead of an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of the many ways of specifying a double literal, without it 1 would be an integer, which would mean you'd be doing integer division, not double division...

```
System.out.println(1 / 3);           // ==> 0   <== Uh oh, integer division 
System.out.println(1. / 3);          // ==> 0.333333
System.out.println(1.0 / 3);         // ==> 0.333333
System.out.println(1d / 3);          // ==> 0.333333
System.out.println(1D / 3);          // ==> 0.333333
System.out.println( (double)1 / 3 ); // ==> 0.3333333
```

Is it syntactic sugar? maybe not, more of a trick in my opinion. I'd prefer 1d, as the intent is clearer.

Comment: `System.out.println( (double)1 / 3 );`

Answer (score 0):

a) 1. is equal to 1.0. It means you want to use as a double. In case you wanted to use floats you would use 1.0f. In case you wanted to use integers you would use 1. Finally for long you would do 1L.

b) I you would use 1 then you would be using an integer but java would transform it into a double as it would detect that the divisor is a double. To prevent this kind of dynamic conversions, it's better to stick to a common numerical type.